# Regular Expression For Arabic Language

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression that matches each word in a sentence:

My regular expression:"`\b(\w+)\b`"

Result:
[image: RegExp matching Arabic image]

While it works well with English Words. It does not work when using Arabic words. 
How could I accomplish the same feat for Arabic words?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this:-

```
function HasArabicCharacters(text)
{
    var arregex = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    alert(arregex.test(text));
}
```

Arabic character set of list

```
[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]
```

### Arabic script in Unicode:

As of **Unicode 6.1**, the Arabic script is contained in the following blocks:

```
Arabic (0600—06FF, 225 characters)
Arabic Supplement (0750—077F, 48 characters)
Arabic Extended-A (08A0—08FF, 39 characters)
Arabic Presentation Forms-A (FB50—FDFF, 608 characters)
Arabic Presentation Forms-B (FE70—FEFF, 140 characters)
Rumi Numeral Symbols (10E60—10E7F, 31 characters)
Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols (1EE00—1EEFF, 143 characters)
```

*Contents are taken from **wikipedia - [Arabic script in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Unicode_block)***

Comment: An [updated regex](https://gist.github.com/rrshaban/fe18eb4bf3e2cff3a929) with full support, as laid out in the latest Unicode standard:
`[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\uFDF0-\uFDFD]`. Test it out [on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/UC6fwxYhJ7)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest this :

```
\p{InArabic}
```

Comment: I'd tested it and it was correct. As far as I know, it's an standard syntax in regex. For example, you can check more details [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with function to translate Aracbic Characters list, Its very simple to do.

As Like :

```
function (regexStr) {
   regexStr = replace(regexStr,"ۿ","\u0600");
   regexStr = replace(regexStr,"؀","\u06FF");

   return regexStr;
}
```

Or in another idea replacing [alf] and [ya] to see your text direction correctly

```
var regexStr = "/[[alf]-[ya]]/";

 function (regexStr) {
   regexStr = replace(regexStr,"[alf]","\u0600");
   regexStr = replace(regexStr,"[ya]","\u06FF");

   return regexStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking search Arabic words
An updated regex from  Razi Shaban above

[\u0600-\u06ff]+|[\u0750-\u077f]+|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]+|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]+|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]+|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]+|[\ufe70-\ufefc]+|[\uFDF0-\uFDFD]+