# Regex validation Comma Separated Words - Foreign Charcters

Tags: c#, regex

I am developing an application in Arabic-English language, so i needed a Regex that validates to a set of separated words, here is my RegEx:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+(,[a-zA-Z]+)*)?$
```

This works flawless for me but as you see the charters specified is in English, i want this for Arabic language.

Can this expression be altered to accept other charters either Arabic or even maybe some other language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of restricting to a set of alphabetical character, exclude the characters that mark the end of your word.

```
^([^,]+(,[^,]+)*)?$
```

If you really want to match Arabic characters, see: [regular expression For Arabic Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323596/regular-expression-for-arabic-language)