# Delete the Arabic characters in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to delete the Arabic characters in Notepad++?
I have the file like this I want to replace the Arabic characters to empty string...

> Dua after Maghrib Prayer The following Dua is recommended to be
>   recited after Magrib Prayer: ثِغْ اللهِ ا شٌَّدْ ا شٌَّدِ ١ْ . اَ
>   ٌٍُّّٰٙ اِ یِّْٔ اَعْبَ هٌَُ ُِٛجِجَبدِ سَدْ زَِّهَ َٚ ػَضَائِ
>   غَِْفِشَرِهَ َٚ ا جٌَّٕبحَ ا بٌَّٕسِ َٚ کُ ثَ ١ٍَِّخٍ َٚ ا فٌَْْٛصَ
>   ثِب جٌَْ خَِّٕ َٚ ا شٌِّظَْٛا فِیْ دَاسِ ا غٌَّلاَ َٚ جَِٛاسِ جَِّٔ
>   ١ِّهَ ذَُِ ذٍَّّ ػَ ١ٍَْ َٚآ ا غٌَّلاَ اَ ٌٍُّّٰٙ بَِ ثِ بَٕ ؼِْٔ خٍَّ
>   فَ هَِّْٕ ٢َ اِ اِلَّْ اَ ذَْٔ اَعْزَغْفِشُنَ َٚ اَرُْٛةُ اِ ١ٌَْهَ .
>   Transliteration: bismil laahir rahmaanir raheem. ALLAAHUMMA INNEE
>   AS-ALOKA MOOJEBAATE RAHMATEKA WA A‟ZAAEMA MAGHFERATEKA WAN NAJAATA
>   MeNAN NAARE WA MIN KULLE BALIYYATIN WAL FAWZA BIL JANNATE WAR RIZWAANA
>   FEE DAARIS SALAAME WA JEWAARE NABIYYEKA MOHAMMADIN A‟LAYHE WA AALEHIS
>   SALAAMO ALLAAHUMMA MAA BENAA MIN NEA‟MATIN FAMINKA LAA ELAAHA ILLAA
>   ANTA ASTAGHFEROKA WA ATOOBO ELAYKA. Translation: In the name of Allah
>   the most Beneficent, the Merciful. O Allah I beseech Thee for the
>   causes of Thy Mercy the right of Thy pardon: safety from every sin;
>   the benefit from every virtue; salvation from (Hell) Fire and every
>   Calamity; achievement of the Paradise and (Thy) Pleasure in the abode
>   of peace; and the proximity of thy prophet Mohammed and his purified
>   progeny peace be on all of them. O Allah! Whatever bounties we have
>   all are from Thee there is no deity except Thee; I beseech Thy
>   forgiveness and turn unto thee.

..
..
I tried with all options like Encode in utf-8 , convert to ANSI but it didn't help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just find the below regex and replace with empty string

`[^\x00-\x80]+`

Answer (score 4):

Adapting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323596/regular-expression-for-arabic-language) for NPP's RegEx syntax:

*Find & Replace* with *Regular Expression* ticked:

```
Find:         [\x{0600}-\x{06ff}]
Replace With:
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Btw it's interesting to note that while N++ has switched PCRE, they must compile it with crippled options, as things like `\p{Arabic}` don't work.