# how to allow only arabic characters in form text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to allow only arabic characters in form text field using jquery

I tried with this but the arrows are not allowing to get back from last line

Let me know if any or edit my code or give any new code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Character Filtering</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function CheckArabicOnly(field) {
                var sNewVal = "";
                var sFieldVal = field.value;

                for (var i = 0; i < sFieldVal.length; i++) {
                    var ch = sFieldVal.charAt(i),
                        c  = ch.charCodeAt(0);

                    if (field.keyCode = '38') {
                    }
                    else if (field.keyCode = '40') {
                        // down arrow
                    }
                    else if (field.keyCode = '37') {
                    }
                    else if (field.keyCode = '39') {
                       // right arrow
                    }

                    if (c < 1536 || c > 1791) {
                        // Discard
                    }
                    else {
                        sNewVal += ch;
                    }
                }

                field.value = sNewVal;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Arabic Only (onchange):
        <input type="text"
               id="txtArabic"
               onchange="CheckArabicOnly(this);"
               onkeypress="CheckArabicOnly(this);"
               onkeyup="CheckArabicOnly(this);"
               onpaste="CheckArabicOnly(this);"  />
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in  arrow i have a problem can you help me here the code

Answer (score 8):

As of Unicode 6.1, the Arabic script is contained in the following blocks (from 
[Regular Expression For Arabic Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323596/regular-expression-for-arabic-language))

```
Arabic (0600—06FF, 225 characters)
Arabic Supplement (0750—077F, 48 characters)
Arabic Extended-A (08A0—08FF, 39 characters)
Arabic Presentation Forms-A (FB50—FDFF, 608 characters)
Arabic Presentation Forms-B (FE70—FEFF, 140 characters)
Rumi Numeral Symbols (10E60—10E7F, 31 characters)
Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols (1EE00—1EEFF, 143 characters)
```

Use a regexp validation for your text field with whatever framework you are using.

```
var isArabic = /^([\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\ufdf0-\ufdfd])*$/g;

// Solution 1: This will add an error class when the input does not match
$("#txtArabic1").change(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("has-error", !isArabic.test(this.value));
})

// Solution 2: This will not let the user type chars that are not arabic
// but seem to fail on my browser... I don't quite get how does 
// javascript splits the string.
$("#txtArabic2").bind('keyup', function(e) {
    var filterFn = isArabic.test.bind(isArabic),
        newValue = this.value.split('').filter(filterFn).join('');

    if (this.value != newValue)
        this.value = newValue;
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbyg317u/2/)

Comment: There is problem with your your code if he paste and i  need live check for that i used one script check my updated code in question but if i use arrows keys i was not able to go to first character or middle characters it remains at last character

Comment: I didn't know you could `toogle` a class :)

Comment: i am soooooooo sorry about that i need the script when the user paste or keyup  dont want to allow english character that the problem about that regards maddog

Comment: can you try your code in  https://jsfiddle.net/ i am not getting please check there and let me is it works or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97887/discussion-between-mad-dog-and-eloims).

Comment: This code does not work, it doesn't even seem to be tested on the jsfiddle, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution tested on PC and Android phones:

```
        $(".filterText").on("input paste", function (e) {
            var formControl = $(e.target);
            var valueBeforeChange = formControl.val();

            var allowedValue = ' ';
            allowedValue += "اآبپتثجچهخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی";//or any collection in any language you want
            allowedValue += "0123456789"; // normal digits
            allowedValue += "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"; // arabic digits
            allowedValue += "،."; // allowed symbols

            var valueAfterChange = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < valueBeforeChange.length; i++) {
                var tmpChar = valueBeforeChange.charAt(i);
                if (allowedValue.indexOf(tmpChar) > -1) valueAfterChange = valueAfterChange + tmpChar;
            }
            formControl.val(valueAfterChange);
        });
```