# Text box should accept both English and Arabic characters using regular expressions

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to create regular expression that should accept both English and Arabic letters. How can I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="ico1" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="enter name " title="enter name ">
```

**JS:**

```
$("#register-form").validate({
  rules: {
    firstname: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2,
      regx: /^[a-zA-Z-,]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*$/
    },
  },
  messages: {
    firstname: {
      required: "<font color='red'>  please enter name </font>",
      minlength: "<font color='red'>minimum length is 2</font>",
      regx: "<font color='red'>enter only english or arabic letters</font>"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please share a working fiddle and a test string?

Comment: There is no `regx` property. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to check several things and here ar emy findings:

- You need to use [`[\u0600-\u06FF]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323596/regular-expression-for-arabic-language) regex to match an Arabic character in JS
- The full regex you need is `var regx = /^[a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF,-][\sa-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF,-]*$/;` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pG7uQ0/2))
- The JQuery validation plugin does not have `regx` rule, you need to use `pattern` from the [additional-methods.js](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.js)
- You can also use a dynamic message for the `minlength` rule: use `minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} characters required!")`

See updated [JS demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3awj76u4/1/):

```js
var regx = /^[a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF,-][\sa-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF,-]*$/; // E.g. هل بعتم بيتكم في نيويورك
$.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
   alert("submitted!");
  }
 });

$("#register-form").validate({
  debug: true, // REMOVE THIS, IT IS FOR DEMO DEBUG ONLY!!!
  rules: {
    firstname: {
      required: true,
      pattern: regx,
      minlength: 2
    },
  },
  messages: {
    firstname: {
      required: "please enter name",
      minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} characters required!"),
      pattern: "enter only english or arabic letters"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="register-form" name="register-form">
 <input type="text" class="ico1" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="enter name " title="enter name "/>
 <input type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: No idea why the snippet refuses to work here, it works fine at https://jsfiddle.net/3awj76u4/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern with `\p{InArabic}` and `\p{Latin}` *Unicode scripts*:

```
...
regx : /^[\p{InArabic}\p{Latin}-,]+(\s?[\p{InArabic}\p{Latin}-, ])*$/
```

Comment: at least, you should try