# How to Detect Arabic or Persian character in string by c#?

Tags: c#

I want to detect **Arabic** or **Persian** character in a string.

For example:

search in string = `"مشخصات، قیمت و خرید لپ تاپ 15 اینچی ایسر مدل Aspire ES1-533-C4UH"`

and return `true`

and search in string=`"Aspire ES1-533-C4UH"`

and return `false`

```
string pattern = @"^[\p{IsArabic}\s\p{N}]+$";
string input = @"مشخصات، قیمت و خرید لپ تاپ 15 اینچی ایسر مدل Aspire ES1-533-C4UH";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.RightToLeft;"

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    if(m.Value !="")
    {
        bool x=true;
    }
    else
        x=false;
}
```

but this doesn not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using this (I'm using it and it works).

This `Regex` accepts all arabic letters by UTF ranges.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]");
return regex.IsMatch(text);
```

Comment: Just curious if you have any experience using unicode blocks, and if this is better or worse? e.g., `\p{IsArabic}` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks

Comment: +1. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323651/21567) for a "little" more information (albeit it is Javascript).

Comment: thanks @BurnsBA ,@Christian.K,@AdrianoRepetti,@Koby Douek. good work my friend,dear koby.

Comment: @HIV88 Happy to help brother.

Comment: Thanks for your hepl @KobyDouek :*