# Check Text field to block Arabic numbers using C# or SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, validation, stored-procedures, numbers, arabic

How to check if the visitor entered any Arabic numbers like (۱, ۲, ۳)

Example: **"Hi ۱ Sir, OK ۲ ۳ Thanks"** in the "Text field" or "Text area" using C# (MVC or Core) or by using SQL Server Stored Procedure?

Note that I send the **value** via API using Ajax to the Controller, so I can process it in C# or send it to SQL Server Procedure to check it, and if it has Arabic numbers then return True or False.

I found many solutions in JavaScript but the visitor can pass it easily in browser console:

```
checkAR = function(){return false};
```

Please Advise.

Comment: This was already asked before plea check it here [How to Detect Arabic or Persian character in string by c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45961993/8795884).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for C#

```
static bool CheckArabicWords(string arabicText)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[\u0600-\u06FF]");
            return regex.IsMatch(arabicText);

        }
```

for sql

```
Create Function [dbo].[IsArabic] (@text varchar(max))
Returns bit
as
begin
if(@text like '%[أ-ي]%')
return 1;
return 0;
end
```

Comment: Thanks Tareq, It worked, do you have a way to do it on sql server procedure?

Comment: give me time to try

Comment: Good Job for SQL