# How to convert from If Statement to Select Case Statement

Tags: regex, vba, if-statement

The following code is okey.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim str As String
    str = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    hasArabic (str)
End Sub

Function hasArabic(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If AscW(Mid(str, i, 1)) >= &H600 And AscW(Mid(str, i, 1)) <= &H6FF Then
            hasArabic = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Please support me how to convert from **If Statement** to **Select Case Statement**.

Comment: You can use Select Case True instead of an If...ElseIf statement. Just take care with when you use it, because it's not a "standard programming construct".

Comment: Alternative [How to Detect Arabic or Persian character in string by c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45961993/10759363) might be  of interest.  You could also possibly use regular expressions.

Comment: @M.Johnstone Do you think using regular expression is better and fast way?

Comment: @M.Johnstone What does your 1st comment mean? Do you have a link to read up on it?

Comment: @DannyColeiro Probably not faster for this case, would require testing.  That would be due to various overheads for creating  the  Regex object and passing the string input via COM. I've wrapped the .Net Regex classes etc  in a project so can more easily translate C# to VBA or could use Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

Comment: @VBasic2008 [select-case-true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794036/select-case-true)  I did do a quick refresher from there.  Will post an answer similar to Tim Williams one.

Comment: @DannyColeiro Would have to test performance.   Creating the Regex object shouldn't be a factor as required to be created once. IMO if can easily be done in VBA it's probably faster if done efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select Case` is a poor choice if you only want to check one condition but:

```
Function hasArabic(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        Select Case AscW(Mid(String:=str, Start:=i, Length:=1))
            Case &H600 To &H6FF
                hasArabic = True
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an Select Case True instead of an If...ElseIf statement.

```
Function HasArabic(ByRef str As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        Dim characterCode As Long
        characterCode = AscW(Mid(str, i, 1))
        Select Case True
            Case (characterCode >= &H600 And characterCode <= &H6FF)
            HasArabic = True
            Exit Function
        End Select
    Next i
End Function

''
' Test if a string contains Arabic characters using regular expressions
'@Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961947/how-to-detect-arabic-or-persian-character-in-string-by-c
'@ReferenceAddin VBScript_RegExp_55
'@Remarks
'   Assuming pattern required [\u0600-\u06ff]
''
Sub ArabicRegEx()
    Dim regExpression As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set regExpression = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim arabicPattern As String
    arabicPattern = "[" & ChrW(&H600) & "-" & ChrW(&H6FF) & "]"
    regExpression.Pattern = arabicPattern
    
    Dim text As String
    text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    Dim isArabic  As Boolean
    isArabic = regExpression.Test(text)
    Debug.Print isArabic
End Sub
```

To use the regular expressions as a Excel macro in a module or could use a predeclared class to initialize the Regex object.

```
Private regExpression As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

Sub CreateArabicRegex()
    Set regExpression = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim arabicPattern As String
    arabicPattern = "[" & ChrW(&H600) & "-" & ChrW(&H6FF) & "]"
    regExpression.Pattern = arabicPattern
End Sub

Function IsArabic(ByRef text As String)
    If regExpression Is Nothing Then
        CreateArabicRegex
    End If
    IsArabic = regExpression.Test(text)
End Function
```

Comment: Quick performance test using VBScript_RegExp_55 appears similar performance.  It probably depends on the size of the string being passed in.

Comment: Note as VBScript_RegExp_55 Regex doesn't appear to have any functionality to unescape a string unlike .Net [Regex.Unescape(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netframework-4.8.1) have to build the pattern using ChrW

Comment: Possible issue distinguishing if Persian or Arabic if that's also required. I think tests for both would return true if just testing  for only that range of characters.